# Keep root element name in JSON generated by Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson 1.9.7 to generated some JSON from my Java objects.

Here is my method to serialize an object to a JSON:

```
public String constructJson(Object object)
        throws EvaluationException {
    try {

        objectMapper.setSerializationConfig(
                objectMapper.getSerializationConfig()
                        .withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
                        .withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
                        .with(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
        );

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error", e);
        throw new EvaluationException("Error", e);
    }
}
```

I am passing the java object which is generated from the XSD schema but it **does not** have the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. Is there any way to tell Jackson to keep the name of that object?

At the moment what it generates is:

```
{"": {
    "generatedId": "EA7EB141D9454433B5E24F374BF25118",....
```

While it should be:

```
{"theNameOfTheRoot": {
    "generatedId": "EA7EB141D9454433B5E24F374BF25118",....
```

My class that I am passing as root to object mapper looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EvaluationType", propOrder = {
    "generatedId",
    "style",
    "status",
    "candidate",
    "texts",
    "evaluationParts"
})
public class EvaluationType {
   .....
}
```

So maybe there is a way to tell Jackson to take the name from the `@XmlType` annotation? Does anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: When you say `theNameOfTheRoot` what are you expecting to see, and where do you expect Jackson to obtain that value from?  It might help if you post some more code.

Comment: Lets say the class name is TheNameOfTheRoot. So I expect it to see from the class. Like all other objects. All other objects doesn't have the XmlRootElement also, but Jackson somehow how the names of them. It just leaves the root element empty,

Comment: I've added some more code

Comment: Your code as is works for me and generates a proper root name. Please include your serialization code.

Comment: Updated the question. Added the method that I am using. Please take a look, because for me it doesn't generate the name of the root element.

Comment: @Perception if this code works for you, maybe its the version that I am using does not have this feature. What version are you using?

Comment: @JimBolster - tested with Jackson 1.9.2

Comment: Not working for me :( still the same... Will try to update to jackson 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put an `@XmlRootElement(name="EvaluationType")` at the top of your class definition it should provide the name.  Or are you stating that you cannot add an `@XmlRootElement` to your class for some reason?

**Update**

Jackson 2 will use the class name for the JSON key if there is no `@XmlRootElement` available.  Jackson 2 requires a new set of maven dependencies, specifically:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I can not add the XmlRootElement annotation. I can't change the XSD file and the files are generated from the XSD document. So I am trying to find another way of doing this.

Comment: In Jackson 2 it states that if you don't have an `@XmlRootElement` then WRAP_ROOT_VALUE will fall back to use the class' name.  If you aren't having any luck with your current version of Jackson you might want to look to upgrade.

Comment: I'll do that thanks. Maybe you can update your answer and put the maven dependency of jackson 2? Then it will be more better answer to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

for version 2.6 use as below

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE,true);      
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE,true);
```